# JointJS select element by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jointjs

I'm using the `joint.shapes.devs.js` plugin to create elements on my jointJS document. I'd like to create a menu that appears when you click on an element in order to show and modify all its data and to delete the element.

As I'm not a backbone expert, I still wonder if it's doable. By extending `joint.shapes.devs.Model`? How?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes , It's doable.

The `paper` triggers `cell:pointerclick` event whenever a cell is clicked. You can attach a callback function to this event . The call back function can then show the menu.

Please refer to the following link for the list all the events triggered by the `paper`. [Jointjs Paper Events](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper:events)

Hope this helps you.